# How draw element of grid layout group higher then other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a grid layout group that contains elements, when you click on an element, it opens a child element that is overlapped by another element [what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XndEw.png)
As an example of what should work [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAnuF.png)

Working with the layout element does not give the desired result, also if you hang a canvas on each element, then the element stops responding to the scroll view mask. You also need to display the element above the others without changing its position through the sibling index

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the render priorities so that the grey part goes over all the images, and the selected image need to have an even higher priority than the grey part.